# How to determine if wire size is correct for given maximum power

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm going to ask a power raise. I'm moving from 3kW + 30% (15A) to 4,5kW + 30% (25A).

I'd  know if my main feed (3m, 2,5mm<sup>2</sup>) is enough to hold the new max rate.

EDIT: I've checked my main feed and it's actually 4 mm^2, not 2,5.

Comment: Where are you?  UK, US (unlikely, given metric measurements), somewhere else?

Comment: I'm in Italy. Thank you Stack Exchange for having me to write unuseful stuff! "comments should be at least 15 characters".

Comment: The right way to have answered my question would have been to [edit] your original question to include the info - not to write a comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

2.5 mm<sup>2</sup> is equivalent to #14 for us Americans, which is required for use on 15 A circuits (or a larger wire). On a 20 A circuit, you need (at least) #12 [4 mm<sup>2</sup>], and for a 30 A circuit (the next step up for your 25 A needs), you need #10 [6 mm<sup>2</sup>].

So, given your current wire size of #14 [2.5 mm<sup>2</sup>], you cannot increase the capacity of the circuit at all.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I'm on a 4mm^2 (I checked the wire mark) that I taught it was 2,5mm^2. So I'll go for 4 kW+30% (20A) instead of 4,5+30% (25A) and I'll be safe.

Comment: Keep in mind American wire ampacity ratings are quite conservative compared to EU ratings. Look at an old copy of NEC table 310.16, and remember those too are conservative.

Comment: To reiterate Harper's point, in the UK a 30A fitting only needs 4mm².  See https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Book/6.3.3.htm

Comment: @MartinBonner UK-style ring circuit or normal "radial" circuits?

Comment: The link is to a section titled "The radial circuit".  You can use 2.5mm² on a ring circuit - but the (not particularly convincing) justification is that the socket is fed with two wires.